# My app slow in device?

Tags: iphone, performance

I am developing one application it's working fine and fast.But in device it's slow.I search in stack overflow one of the reason memory leaks.But no leaks in my app, Tell me the another reason?

Comment: How could we answer this if we don't know how you've written your app? Try using Instruments: http://vafer.org/blog/20080812182921/

Comment: @AlanZeino yah i am using that and try to find.But if any one tell the another cause i think and try that way.Any way tanx for u r link...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The device will be slower than the simulator because it's not as powerful. Are you trying to do a processor or memory intensive task?

Comment: TanQ I will try to do that.....